# Redirect URLs containing specific string to https

Tags: .htaccess, https

I want to redirect my member registration URLs to HTTPS using htaccess. So:
http://example.com/product/register/*

...And any pages under that such as:
http://example.com/product/register/details
http://example.com/product/register/payment

I tried the following, but I'm not sure I'm even on the right track:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond $1 ^(register/*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /product/register/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```